# Question about SharePoint PnP Search Results web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, pnp

I would like in the PnP Search Results web part the query of `{SearchTerms}` to be to show only the accounts that has no period in it.

Is that possible?

If so what do I have to change to:

```
{SearchTerms} Account
```

Comment: Maybe you can try this: {SearchTerms} Account:*.*